Is it possible to define recursive entity structure with Elixir Spark?
defmodule Im.Dsl.Entities.ReceiveCmd do
  def cmd(), do: %Spark.Dsl.Entity{
        name: :rcv,
        describe: "Receive command.",
        target: Im.Commands.Receive,
        ...
        entities: [body: [
          Im.Dsl.Entities.IfCondCmd.cmd(),
          Im.Dsl.Entities.ReceiveCmd.cmd() # end up in infinite loop during compilation
        ]]
}

Is it possible to define an entity that can have the same type of entity as a child?
Context:
I'm defining a DSL for defining semantics of processes with some predefined commands as entities.
In this case, the process sends messages to 2 clients and receives their responses. But I can't add a receive statement within a receive statement:
snd user1, commitRequest
snd user2, commitRequest
rcv {message1, some_user} do
   rcv {message2, some_other_user} do
     ....
   end
end

Is there any alternative recommended way to design such DSLs?

What would be wrong with rcv [{message1, some_user}, {message2, some_other_user}] do in the first place? As for cmd/0, you need to separate declaration apart from execution.

@AlekseiMatiushkin Could work, but it would be nice to have this as a general approach. Eg nesting if-then-else. What do you mean, how can I separate declaration from execution?

Im.Dsl.Entities.ReceiveCmd.cmd() is getting called in compile time. Make it lazy, like {Im.Dsl.Entities.ReceiveCmd., :cmd} and calculate the actual value upon invocation.

Are you sure Spark supports laziness?
It expects @type entities() :: keyword(t()) where t is the entity struct %Spark.Dsl.Entity{...} . And as far as I understand, everything is happening in compile time anyways.
I found though that I can set the recursive_as(), which makes it possible to define the mentioned example, but it is only applicable to direct children.
